# Mostrar imagen subida a STORAGE Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, filesystem

estoy subiendo una imagen usando el Sistema de archivos de laravel, me lo sube correctamente a la carpeta que he creado, en filesystems.php he creado lo siguiente

```php
        'portada' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/portada'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/portada',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ]
```

Ahora estoy intentando acceder a esta imagen desde blade para mostrarla como una foto normal, es un avatar, el nombre de la foto la guardo en la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo y no funciona? O cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la versión de Laravel? ¿Y el sistema operativo? Si tienes un Linux, ¿has creado un link simbólico para unir *public* y *storage*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes obtener esa imagen en un controlador y luego pasarla a blade. Ejemplo:

```
public function getImage($filename){
    $file= Storage::disk('portada')->get($filename);
    return new Response($file,200);
    //También puede ser un redirect o lo que necesites :D
}
```

Comment: ¿no hay ninguna forma de mostrarla directamente desde blade?

Comment: No, al menos que yo sepa. Puesto que debes acceder al disk. Y blade es una plantilla, por lo que tiene ciertas limitaciones. Saludos, si te sirvió de ayuda márcala como útil.